# search special character in mysql string fucntions

Tags: mysql, string, function, character, mariadb

I need to use special character like ( \ ) character in mysql string function and unfortunately it doesn't work properly!for example couldn't search this character alone (locate-instr-substring_index-concat and even in set variable value are function that i need and test )

like thses

```
SELECT LOCATE("\", "Schools.co\m", 1) AS MatchPosition;
select SUBSTRING_INDEX("footba\l","\",1)
```

I will appreciate if anybody could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash needs to be escaped.  To fix your `SUBSTRING_INDEX` example, consider the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("footba\\l","\\",1) FROM dual
```

Here, backslash has to be escaped *both* in the string literal and in the text to match.

To escape a literal backslash inside a `LIKE` expression, use *four* backslashes, e.g.

```
SELECT 'match' FROM dual WHERE "footba\\l" LIKE '%\\\\%';
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks dear Tim so based on your help ;I  have to change my input to create double backslash and then search for Double Backslash

Comment: @RickJames Ironically, your escape character also appears to have been consumed.  You may want to comment again without using backticks.

Comment: (Re-issue) The escape character (`\\`) is consumed by each layer of API between you and the actual engine. Usually doubling is enough, but if there are extra layers, you may need to double that. Experiment until you get the right answer.